# Simple question about File class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, file-io

I'm trying to read from a file in kotlin using the File class. It's just a simple txt file with a list of names with each name occupying an independent row. This is my project structure: [image]

and here's my function for pulling out a name depending on the day of the year:

```
private fun getNameOfTheDay(): String {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val day = cal[Calendar.DATE]

        return File("data${File.separator}names.txt")
            .bufferedReader()
            .lineSequence()
            .elementAt(day - 1)
    }
```

I keep on getting a FileNotFound exception so I would assume that my file path is somehow wrong... What am I doing wrong here? Sorry for the dumb question, I'm still learning. By the way the function shown above is called from the MainActivity. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filenames can be absolute or relative. Absolute filenames start from the top level (e.g. the root directory on Unix-like filesystems, which Macs have; or a drive letter on Windows), and so specify the filename unambiguously. Relative filenames don't, and so give a file in (or in relation to) the current working directory.

In this case, `data/names.txt` is a relative filename. It assumes that the current directory has a subdirectory called `data`, and refers to a file in that.

However, the file is actually in the directory `app/src/main/java/com/example/mynameis/data/` within your project — so this would only work if the current directory was `/<pathToYourProject>/app/src/main/java/com/example/mynameis/`, which is highly unlikely! So that probably explains the failure.

I don't know about Android projects, but in normal JVM projects the standard practice is to put data files in a `src/main/resources/` directory. Gradle (or Maven) knows to copy them into the classpath when building the project. You would then load it from the classpath, e.g. with:

```
javaClass.getResource("data/names.txt").readText()
```

See e.g. [this question](/questions/42739807/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-resources-in-kotlin) for more details and variations.

The advantage of loading from the classpath instead of a file path is that you don't need to know exactly where the file is; it could be loose on the filesystem, or bundled into a jar or other archive (even compressed), with ways to select between different versions depending on the run profile — all completely transparent to your code.

As I said, I don't know Android, and can't find any direct answers on StackOverflow. ([This](/questions/7976141/get-uri-of-mp3-file-stored-in-res-raw-folder-in-android) question seems to suggest using a `android.resource://` URI, but I don't know if that would apply here.) Maybe [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/Resources) [external](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Resources) sites can give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You should try "data\names.txt". Oftentimes slashes don't work for file paths.

Comment: Woops, yeah sorry, I forgot to mention that I was on Mac. Changed the / to File.Separator.

Comment: `/` generally works fine on Macs (this century, anyway). Of course, `File.separator` is safer and should work on even more platforms, but I doubt that explains the problem here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).